# Find what number is currently on the screen

Tags: python, image, numbers, ocr, pyautogui

I posted something similar yesterday but I have some new obstacles. The main goal is speed when it comes to this project. I need this to be done in less than half a second. What I’m trying to do is automate a bingo game and what I need to do is find a way to tell what number was called. I have the spots and number locations on the bingo board taken care of with preset coordinates that I make before each game. All I need to do is find what number was picked which I would assume would be by converting the following image to text. When I use pytesseract, it only finds some numbers and not others. For example, it would find 37 every time it showed up but it wouldn't find 18. There are only 75 numbers that could potentially be called throughout the game and they all show up in the same exact spot. Do you have any ideas on how I could either use a different OCR plugin or maybe another way to click on the image fast? Pyautogui was also too slow when I tried clicking on the image while looping through all 75 saved images. Thanks guys!

[Number that I'm trying to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUH1n.png)

Comment: How do the pictures of numbers appear in the screen in the first place? Do you have a folder with 75 images and your program picks which image to show in each coordinate?

Comment: Because if you have the images that are shown, as separate files (one file per number), doesn't it means that you already know the number? Without having to use any OCR? i.e. file num_43.png is number 43, and so on.... Even if they're being chosen at random, you can save the number when you make the choice. And if the files are systematically named, like in my example, it would be easy to programmatically make a dictionary holding all the `file : number` relationships.